# how to remove string ending with specific string

Tags: python, string

I have file names like

```
ios_g1_v1_yyyymmdd
ios_g1_v1_h1_yyyymmddhhmmss
ios_g1_v1_h1_YYYYMMDDHHMMSS
ios_g1_v1_g1_YYYY
ios_g1_v1_j1_YYYYmmdd
ios_g1_v1
ios_g1_v1_t1_h1
ios_g1_v1_ty1_f1
```

I would like to remove only the suffix when it matches the string YYYYMMDDHHMMSS  OR yyyymmdd  OR YYYYmmdd OR    YYYY

my expected output would be

```
ios_g1_v1
ios_g1_v1_h1
ios_g1_v1_h1
ios_g1_v1_g1
ios_g1_v1_j1
ios_g1_v1
ios_g1_v1_t1_h1
ios_g1_v1_ty1_f1
```

How can I achieve this in python using regex ? i tried with something like below, but it didn't work

```
word_trimmed_stage1 = re.sub('.*[^YYYYMMDDHHMMSS]$', '', filename)
```

Comment: Does the `yyyymmdd` and the likes of it stand for date patterns?

Comment: is yyymmdd a date pattern or is it a literal string ?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: its not date pattern..just string like

Comment: Also: **Why do you want to use regex for this**?

Comment: @AkshaySehgal please don't use comments to advertise or summarize an answer. This is not a discussion forum.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel - There is no advertising here. the pattern was simple and didnt deserve a specific answer, but i have added additional explanation which could not be added here. Please dont assume without any basis. Plus there is no SO rule that someone who answers cant also post comments. The comments encourage on-topic discussion which both my comment and my answer are.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel also, your previous comment `"i tried with something like below, but it didn't work" What happened when you tried it? How is that different from what is supposed to happen?` is invalid. OP made an attempt, posted their code, and it didnt result in the expected output, without any error. That is sufficient to ask a question, as per [ask]

Comment: Can you read your title again? "with ..." - with what?

Comment: @mkrieger1, the title definitely needs an edit.

Comment: " it didnt result in the expected output, without any error. That is sufficient to ask a question" No, it isn't. "It didn't result in [what I wanted]" isn't a description of behaviour. "It **did** result in [this concrete, specific thing, which is other than what I wanted]" is.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Its not easy to do that with Regex however. OP can easily show where it worked, not easy to show where it didn't because of the nature of how regex works. He could have added a few cases, but this is a simple example of `My regex for turning "this" into "this" failed, how should i fix this` is a valid question in my opinon. Its reproducible, shows an attempt, and since it doesnt result in an error, doesnt need an error trace. The title is another story though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, your pattern involves `Year, Month, Day, Hour, Minute, Second` characters with any number of repeated characters in that order, starting with an underscore and case-insensitive.

Try this pattern `r"_Y+M*D*H*M*S*"` -

```
import re

regex_pattern = r"_Y+M*D*H*M*S*"
result = [re.sub(regex_pattern,'',i, flags=re.IGNORECASE) for i in l]
result
```

```
['ios_g1_v1',
 'ios_g1_v1_h1',
 'ios_g1_v1_h1',
 'ios_g1_v1_g1',
 'ios_g1_v1_j1',
 'ios_g1_v1',
 'ios_g1_v1_t1_h1',
 'ios_g1_v1_ty1_f1']
```

#### EXPLANATION

1. The `_` matches the underscore at start of the patter
2. The `flags=re.IGNORECASE` makes this pattern search case-insensitive
3. The `Y+` matches at least 1 instance of `Y`
4. Then the `M*D*H*M*S*` match any instances of these specific characters after the initial `Y` in that order (starting 0 instances)

Answer (score 0):

You can be explicit and use the exact patterns that you have identified, optionally case insensitive with `re.I`:

```
files = ['ios_g1_v1_yyyymmdd',
 'ios_g1_v1_h1_yyyymmddhhmmss',
 'ios_g1_v1_h1_YYYYMMDDHHMMSS',
 'ios_g1_v1_g1_YYYY',
 'ios_g1_v1_j1_YYYYmmdd',
 'ios_g1_v1',
 'ios_g1_v1_t1_h1',
 'ios_g1_v1_ty1_f1']

files2 = [re.sub('_(?:YYYYMMDDHHMMSS|yyyymmdd|YYYYmmdd|YYYY)$', '', x, flags=re.I)
          for x in files]
```

*NB. with `re.I` you only need one of `yyyymmdd`/`YYYYmmdd`.*

Compressed variant:

```
files2 = [re.sub('_YYYY(?:MMDD(?:HHMMSS)?)?$', '', x, flags=re.I) for x in files]
```

Output:

```
['ios_g1_v1',
 'ios_g1_v1_h1',
 'ios_g1_v1_h1',
 'ios_g1_v1_g1',
 'ios_g1_v1_j1',
 'ios_g1_v1',
 'ios_g1_v1_t1_h1',
 'ios_g1_v1_ty1_f1']
```

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer:** this is a non regex approach; @mozway posted a good regex approach

```
files = ['ios_g1_v1_yyyymmdd',
 'ios_g1_v1_h1_yyyymmddhhmmss',
 'ios_g1_v1_h1_YYYYMMDDHHMMSS',
 'ios_g1_v1_g1_YYYY',
 'ios_g1_v1_j1_YYYYmmdd',
 'ios_g1_v1',
 'ios_g1_v1_t1_h1',
 'ios_g1_v1_ty1_f1']

lst=[]
for filenames in files:
  k=[]
  for x in range(len(filenames)-1):
    if filenames[x]=='y' or filenames[x]=='Y':
        if filenames[x+1]=='y' or filenames[x+1]=='Y':
            break
    else:
        k.append(filenames[x])
  if k[-1]=='_':
    lst.append(''.join(k)[:-1])
  else:
    lst.append(''.join(k))
    
print(lst)

#['ios_g1_v1', 'ios_g1_v1_h1', 'ios_g1_v1_h1', 'ios_g1_v1_g1', 'ios_g1_v1_j1', 'ios_g1_v', 'ios_g1_v1_t1_h', 'ios_g1_v1_t1_f']
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be another approach

```py
renamed_files = []
for filename in files:
    if filename.split("_")[-1].lower().startswith("y"):
        renamed_files.append("_".join(filename.split("_")[:-1]))
    else:
        renamed_files.append(filename)
        
print(renamed_files)
```

You can also make good use of `list()` function instead of `append` one element at a time:

```py
renamed_files = list(
    "_".join(filename.split("_")[:-1])
    if filename.split("_")[-1].lower().startswith("y")
    else filename
    for filename in files
    )
```

Both approach should produce the same output:
Output:

```
['ios_g1_v1',
 'ios_g1_v1_h1',
 'ios_g1_v1_h1',
 'ios_g1_v1_g1',
 'ios_g1_v1_j1',
 'ios_g1_v1',
 'ios_g1_v1_t1_h1',
 'ios_g1_v1_ty1_f1']
```

Answer (score -3):

Try removing everything after the last `_` detected.

Comment: Did you read the question? "I would like to remove only the suffix **when it matches** the string YYYYMMDDHHMMSS OR ..."